# Applying cyclic learning rate in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I want to test the cycliclearning rate in Keras. However, just at the end of the first epoch, I am getting this TypeError error. Any ideas how to properly define the cyclic learning rate in this case?

Epoch 1/10000
hist = model.fit_generator(generator=training_generator,validation_data = calibration_generator, epochs = n_epoch,
510/510 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.0111 - mae: 0.0772  Traceback (most recent call last):

File "H:\my_data\from drive C my PC Spet_2022\Code\Phase_2_Cyclic_Learning.py", line 303, in

hist = model.fit_generator(generator=training_generator,validation_data
calibration_generator, epochs = n_epoch,

File "C:\Users\bluesky\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-
packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 2507, in fit_generator
return self.fit(

File "C:\Users\bluesky\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-
packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None

File "C:\Users\bluesky\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site- packages\keras\utils\generic_utils.py", line 965, in update
self._values[k] = [v * value_base, value_base]

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'CyclicalLearningRate' and 'int'

My code:

```
pip install tensorflow-addons
from tensorflow_addons.optimizers import CyclicalLearningRate


model = Sequential()


input_dim = len(input_cols_idx)
batch_size = batch_size_gen


model.add(Dense(units=hidden_layer1_neurons, input_dim= input_dim,
        kernel_initializer = initializers.RandomNormal(mean=0.0, stddev=0.05)))


model.add(Activation(activation_1)) 
model.add(Dense(units=1))
model.add(Activation(activation_2)) 



# Create Cyclic Learning Rate and Callbacks

cyclical_learning_rate = CyclicalLearningRate(
initial_learning_rate=0.000008,
maximal_learning_rate=0.001,
step_size=2360,
scale_fn=lambda x: 1 / (2.0 ** (x - 1)),
scale_mode='cycle')

model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', 
 optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=cyclical_learning_rate), metrics=['mae'])

checkpointer = callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(filepath=("%s/%s.h5" % (model_dir,model_name)), 
monitor='val_loss', mode='min', save_best_only=True) 

# val_loss                                  
reduce = callbacks.ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_mae',factor=0.25, mode='min',
                             patience = lr_reduce_patience,  epsilon=epsilon,
                             cooldown=0,  min_lr= min_lr)    # Later versions of Keras 
uses min_delta inplace of epsilon
earlystop = callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_mae', min_delta = earlystop_min_delta, 
                            patience=earlystop_patience, verbose=0, mode='min')

csv_logger = CSVLogger('%s/%s_log.csv'%(model_dir, model_name), append=True, 
  separator=';')
```

#-----------Training

```
hist = model.fit_generator(generator=training_generator,validation_data = 
  calibration_generator, epochs = n_epoch,
                use_multiprocessing=False, callbacks = [reduce, earlystop,checkpointer, 
csv_logger]) #TensorBoard(log_dir='./logs')])
               # workers=6)    ,plot_losses        
cost=pd.DataFrame(hist.history)
```

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: Attempt some debugging and show the results of possible

Comment: @furas: I included the full error message.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the solution for the problem (after struggling with it myself).

When you remove the ReduceLROnPlateau callback it works for me (tf=2.11.0 and tfa=0.19.0).